# Как расположить grid вертикально,а не горизонатльно

Tags: html, css

Как расположить grid вертикально,а не горизонтально,чтоб было 2 столбика с доставкой и магазинами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.gicons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gicons">
    <img src="static/images/image.psd (3).png" alt="">
    <h1>Бесплатная доставка</h1>
 <h5>И бесплатный возврат.
    <br>
Сроки доставки можно узнать
<br>
на странице оформления заказа.</h5>
<p><a href="#">Подробнее ></a></p>

</div>

<div class="gicons">
    <img src="static/images/image.psd (4).png" alt="">
    <h1>Ближайшие магазины</h1>
<h5>Посмотрите, какие магазины
    <br>
наших официальных партнёров
<br>
находятся ближе к вам.</h5>
<p><a href="#">Найти на карте ></a></p>



</div>
```

Comment: "чтоб было 2 столбика с доставкой и магазинами" – а можно как-то более понятно? Каких столбика? Что конкретно Вы хотите получить?

Comment: Сначала думал дай ка помогу, а потом посмотрел на html и расхотелось))

Comment: а что не так с Html ?)

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так можно сделать, когда приложили пример, хоть понятнее стало, что делать)

```css
.gicons {
  text-align: center;
}
.gicons-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gicons-wrapper">
  <div class="gicons">
    <img src="static/images/image.psd (3).png" alt="">
    <h1>Бесплатная доставка</h1>
    <h5>И бесплатный возврат.
    <br>
    Сроки доставки можно узнать
    <br>
    на странице оформления заказа.</h5>
    <p><a href="#">Подробнее ></a></p>
</div>

  <div class="gicons">
    <img src="static/images/image.psd (4).png" alt="">
    <h1>Ближайшие магазины</h1>
    <h5>Посмотрите, какие магазины
    <br>
    наших официальных партнёров
    <br>
    находятся ближе к вам.</h5>
    <p><a href="#">Найти на карте ></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо,получилось )

Comment: а как сделать между этими двумя столбиками расстояние поменьше ?

Comment: @atr за расстояние отвечает gap: 30px;. Он вместо padding или margin. КОгда верстаете на grid или flex  - для отступов использовать лучше gap;. Таким образом вы не будете мучаться от того, что первый и последний элементы тоже имеют отступ и поэтому не прилегают к краю контейнера. gap создаёт отступы исключительно между элементами и не даёт отступ крайним элементам

Comment: Если правильно подсказал, ставить нужно галочку и стрелочку вверх).